# Perturbing Coefficients of Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, implicit-function-theorem

I'm stuck on 7. (c) (see problem below) proving that this polynomial has no more than $m$ roots (so far I have that it has $\geq m$ roots). I am trying to proceed by contradiction, assuming that there is such a coefficient vector $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ contained in every neighbourhood about $c$ (our coefficient vector given in the problem) such that $$x^n + d_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + d_0$$ has $> m$ roots. My gut tells me to take a sequence of these $d$s that converge to $c$ and use the continuity of functions guaranteed by the Implicit function theorem but this doesn't seem to lead me anywhere since these functions are only guaranteed on neighbourhoods about $d$ that need not contain $c$. Can someone give me a hint? What should I be focusing on?

[image: Problem in question]

Comment: Try to first prove a stronger and more useful variant of (b): for _any_ neighborhood $V_r$ of $r$ there is a neighborhood $U_r$ of... such that...

Comment: Ok I think I've got that. I used the implicit function thm to prove the existence of a neighbourhood, $U_r'$, about $(c_0, ...,c_{n-1})$ and a ($C^1$) function $f: U_r' \rightarrow  B_r(\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon$ that "provides the root" of whatever new polynomial we get. Also, $\epsilon$ can chosen smaller so that $B_r(\epsilon) \subset V_r$ and, by continuity of $f$, we have a guaranteed neighbourhood, $U_r$, of $(c_0, ...,c_{n-1})$ that $f$ maps to $B_r(\epsilon)$. Perhaps I'm overlooking something important because I still don't know where to go from here

Comment: Based on (a), one can choose small enough $V_r$ neighborhoods so that $f'(r)$ keeps the same sign inside each $V_r$ (thus $f$ injective), and also all $V_r$ are mutually disjoint. Then any polynomial with coefficients in the intersection $U$ of the corresponding $U_r$ will have exactly one root in each of the $V_r$. Still remains to be proven that "small enough" perturbations introduce no _additional_ roots.

Comment: Oh that's the part I'm stuck on! Can I proceed with some variation of my idea from the original question?

Comment: $f(x)$ is non-zero on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \cup{V_r}$ so there must be an $m \gt 0$ such as $f(x) \ge m$ for all $x \notin V_r$. By continuity, there would be a neighborhood $U'$ in the $(d_i)$ space where the perturbed polynomial is strictly $\gt 0$. Now intersect the previous $U$ and this $U'$.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this one. I'm not seeing how considering $U \cap U'$ might help us. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: First off, I meant $|f(x)|$ in the previous comment. Main point remains however that the perturbed polynomial would have no roots in $U'$. Now, $U \cap U'$ is a neighborhood of the $(c_i)$ coefficient vector, and for any $(d_i) \in U \cap U'$ the perturbed polynomial would have exactly $m$ roots, one in each of $U \cap V_r$, and no other roots outside $\cup V_r$ since the absolute value is $\gt 0$ on $\mathbb R \setminus \cup V_r$ for all $(d_i) \in U'$.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with this still, sorry. I think I do not understand the definition of $U'$, is the $(d_i)$ space just the space of coefficient vectors?

Comment: `Main point remains however that the perturbed polynomial would have no roots in U′ ` That was carelessly worded. Rephrasing better: any perturbed polynomial with coefficients $(d_i) \in U'$ would have no roots in $\mathbb R \setminus \cup V_r$. Idea is to construct a set of $m$ neigborhoods of $(c_i)$ where any perturbed polynomial has exactly 1 root _near_ the original root, plus 1 other neighborhood where any perturbed polynomial is guaranteed to _not_ have any roots elsewhere. The intersection of all those then proves it. Guess I could formalize it into a full answer if still not clear.

Comment: Ahh I see what's going on now! Thanks so much.